# Transpose of a matrix and printing result in same format

Tags: python, matrix, programming-languages, transpose

Write a python function transpose (m) that takes as input two dimensional matrix using this row wise representation and returns the transpose of matrix using same representation

Eg. assume input is always a non empty matrix

```
>>>transpose ([[1,4,9]])

[[1] , [4], [9]]

>>>transpose  ([[1,3,5], [2,4,6]])

[[1,2], [3,4] , [5,6]]
```

yeh! new to python can anyone help with this

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump, and because it's not a real question. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Please also read [this open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You should try numpy for this. It has a [transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) function. From the docs:

```
>>> x = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
>>> x
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> np.transpose(x)
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
>>> x = np.ones((1, 2, 3))
>>> np.transpose(x, (1, 0, 2)).shape
(2, 1, 3)
```

Comment: Using function transpose